# how to make checkbox checked by default in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, checkbox

I want checkbox checked as default value.

**HTML :**

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-6" ng-class="{ 'has-error': pForm.caddress.$dirty && pForm.caddress.$error.required }">                          
    <label class="control-label l_font" for="address">Current Address*</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" type="text" name="caddress" placeholder="Current address" ng-model="caddress" ng-disabled ="!pEditMode"  ng-required = "true" >
    </textarea>
    <span ng-show="pForm.caddress.$dirty && pForm.caddress.$error.required" class="help-block">Current Address is required</span>                                
</div>


<div class="form-group col-sm-6" ng-class="{ 'has-error': pForm.paddress.$dirty && pForm.paddress.$error.required }">
    <label class="control-label l_font" for="address">Permanent Address*</label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="sameAddrres" ng-checked="copyAddress()" ng-disabled ="!pEditMode" />
    <i class="inside">Select if Permanent address is same as Current address</i>

    <style>
        .inside 
        {
        font-size: 12px;
        }
    </style>
    <textarea class="form-control" type="text" name="paddress" placeholder="Permanent address" 
    ng-model="paddress" ng-disabled ="!pEditMode || sameAddrres" ng-required = "true" ></textarea>
    <span ng-show="pForm.paddress.$dirty && pForm.paddress.$error.required" class="help-block">Permanent Address is required</span>
</div>
```

I am using a function to copy the current address value to permanent address value if check box is checked.

**Controller :**

```
$scope.copyAddress = function(){

    if($scope.sameAddrres == true){

        $scope.paddress = $scope.caddress;
    }            
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The controller is not complete. Looks like you have initialized the `$scope.sameAddress = false` or not defined.

On check of checkbox, set the sameAddress filed to `true`, based on a function to check if both the values are same, when loading the controller.

Comment: But in controller i used a condition if($scope.sameAddrres == true)

Comment: When i checked the check box then the value from current address field is copied to permanent address field. I am storing all the values in the backend and getting response when page is refreshed or login again.  But when i refresh the page the checkbox gets disappeared so the field gets enabled. so can you help me where i am making mistake.

Comment: Refresh is destroying old values and creating a new controller instance.  Thus the previous values are lost. At the controller after rendering the page, check the values at both the fields, if equal, set the input checkbox modal to true, which is false by default.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use ng-model with ng-checked according to [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked).
You can remove the ng-chekced and put watch on this property like so:

```
 $scope.$watchCollection('sameAddrres', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if(newValue) 
       $scope.paddress = $scope.caddress;
});
```